# Seg Fault when running fgets() in a function outside of main() on ESXi

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, fgets, esxi

I am creating a tool for managing my VMs on my ESXi servers. I am parsing the output from `popen()` from running `vim-cmd` commands.

The issue is when calling `fgets()` in a function outside of `main()`. If I call it inside of `main()` it works without issue.

Code:

```
int main() {
    FILE* fp = NULL;
    char path[255] = {0};
    char* cmd = "vim-vmd vmsvc/getsummary";

    fp = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    int cnt = 0;
    while(fgets(path, 255, fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", path);
    }
    pclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

This will work. But if I place all of that code into a function and then call that function from `main()` it will seg fault on `fgets()`.

This crashes...

```
void myfunc() {
    FILE* fp = NULL;
    char path[255] = {0};
    char* cmd = "vim-vmd vmsvc/getsummary";

    fp = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    int cnt = 0;
    while(fgets(path, 255, fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", path);
    }
    pclose(fp);
    return;
}

int main() {
    myfunc();
    return 0;
}
```

I am building this on Ubuntu 12.04 since the glibc version is 2.14 on this version and my ESXi server is 2.17.

Comment: please show us the code that crashes

Comment: Why are you pasting code that actually works? Edit you question and add the relevant code that causes the segmentation fault.

Comment: I thought my explanation would have covered that but I added it...

Comment: the code can't segfault unless you have a very small stack and you overflow it. Try to comment one by one operation, change buff to something smaller like 32 chars. Debug it yourself.

Comment: Great advice why didn't I ever think of that

Comment: You need to run this with your debugger. The debugger will tell you more.

Comment: you should not printf a string that you do not know is null terminated, at least make the buffer one larger and set a 0 in the last place